Python Azure Time Trigger Function not showing in Azure Portal after successful deployment from VS code
I have a Time Trigger Function written in Python 3.11.9 in Visual Studio code. The function runs successfully locally (using F5). When I deploy the function to the Azure portal from Visual Studio Code, it shows as "Deployment successful." in both the Output and Azure tab


However, when I go to my Function App on Azure Portal, the App files show in the function section

but my time trigger function does not shows in the overview section of the function app in the Azure Portal

When deploying from VS Code, I tried deploying from;

the Local Workspace section on the Azure tab


The Resource section on Azure tab




Through terminal


(which gives a slightly different output, see below)

But none of these methods were able to fix the problem of the Azure Function not showing up on my Azure Portal Function App.
here is the function code with imports(function_app.py)
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import requests
import json
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pandas as pd
import csv
from flatten_json import flatten
#for extending csv file for 1 day at a time holidays
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin
#used to save to specific folder 
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version
from io import BytesIO
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from io import BytesIO 
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential 
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
#sharepoint
# import necessary modules
from shareplum import Site
import pandas as pd
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum.site import Version
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from IPython.display import display
from tabulate import tabulate
from pandas import json_normalize
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
import pandas as pd
import io
import errno
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pathlib import Path
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.keys import KeyClient

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.schedule(schedule="0 */5 * * * *", arg_name="myTimer", run_on_startup=True,
              use_monitor=False) 
def timer_trigger(myTimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    if myTimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function executed.')


    #full script below this, inline with function so it runs when the function runs 

The modules used (requirements.txt file)
flatten-json==0.1.14 
ipython==8.12.3 
numpy==1.26.4 
Office365-REST-Python-Client==2.5.7 
pandas==2.2.0 
python-dotenv==1.0.1 
requests==2.31.0 
scikit-learn==1.4.2 
SharePlum==0.5.1 
simple-salesforce==1.12.5 
tabulate==0.9.0

local.settings.json file ( I have tried using "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" and not using this, both gave the same result of no function being present on Azure Portal)
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}

FIXED : adding the additional requirements from Ikhtesam's answer below fixed this issue
FUNCTION FAILING TO EXECUTE WITHIN PORTAL
My function is now showing in the portal and attempting to run every 5 mins (as intended) but failing to execute on each run

below is the Invocation Traces

And Invocation Traces Description

Running the Query in Application Insights

Logs Message:

Method of retrieving KeyVault Values:
keyVaultName = "<key-vault-name>"
KVUri = f"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net"

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = SecretClient(vault_url=KVUri, credential=credential)

username = client.get_secret("username").value
password = client.get_secret("password").value
security_token = client.get_secret("security-token").value
domain = client.get_secret("domain").value

Key Vault Reference :

Configuration Section :


Access Policies blocked due to RBAC

Access Configuration

These are the roles I currently have

-UPDATE
The enterprise/function/service app role:

Access Denied :


please share your function code

please share the modules you have used in your function

I see there are some imports in your function file, can you add them as well

Hi Ikhtesam, I have amended my question to provide these

Please add all the modules in the requirements.txt file. I have added following modules in requirements.txt which are used in function_app.py.
azure-functions
requests
simple-salesforce
pandas
flatten-json
python-dotenv
SharePlum
Office365-REST-Python-Client
numpy
ipython
scikit-learn
tabulate
azure-identity
azure-keyvault
azure-core
azure-storage-blob

I have same code alike you in function_app.py file.

By making above modification in requirements.txt file, I am able to deploy the function successfully to function app.




Update-
To get the secret value from key vault in the function app, perform the following steps-

Enable Managed Identity in function app.



Copy the Object(Principal) Id from above and add it in Access policies of your key vault instance in order to grant permission to your function app.



Click Next -> Review + create

Once it is created, you will get the expected response.

Hi there, the additions to the requirements.txt file worked, thanks! (Although the function fails to execute in portal for some reason)
I was wondering what you method was to retrieve these additional requirements. I ran 'pigar generate' to generate the requirements.txt but I'm wondering why It didn't fully populate the requirements.txt file with all necessary requirements

@AidanGoldie Can you please share the error message you are getting in portal

@IkhtesamArfin I have amended the question to show the error message, thanks!

@AidanGoldie Can you click on the invocation traces showing in Monitor blade and share the error message

My apologies, this has been added now

@AidanGoldie Error is on username which you are trying to print in your function code. By using the default timer trigger function and the code you shared in the question you shouldn't get any error.

The error message seems to say that I don't have authorisation to access the Key vault (error 403, in the 9th section after request to access KeyVault), and because I can't access the Key Vault then the code does not recognise 'username', I have run the script locally and it runs with no errors and is able to grab these values from KeyVault, but on Portal it seems to fail

@AidanGoldie have you added the key vault reference in the Configuration of function app post deployment?

I have not, I cannot see where to do this in Function App > Settings > Configuration. However I do have a 'KEY_VAULT_NAME' variable in Function App > Settings > Environment Variable, should I delete and re-add this value? (I updated the question)

I must use Azure RBAC permission model in Access Configuration tab and so cannot access the 'Access Policies' tab at all, is there a workaround you know of for this? Question updated, thanks!

@AidanGoldie Where have you added the roles? You need to enable the managed identity in function app and the add those roles

You need to add the roles in Key vault IAM and choose user and add your function app name there to grant permission.

I already had this role in place for my function app, although I believe this is a managed identity or something similar as it has the title 'Enterprise Application'. This was set up for me so do not have access to it (see bottom of question). Even with this set up, the error persists

@AidanGoldie In this way, you need to assign the role to your function app.

I have done this but the same error persists where it throws a 403 error when trying to access the key vault and therefore cannot access any of the secret values

@AidanGoldie I believe it is something to do with how you have granted the permissions. By using the steps given in my answer, I am able to fetch the secret value in function app

Interesting, so your function runs in Azure portal with no errors? and you do this by assigning the function apps managed instance the role of KeyVault Administrator within the Key Vault

@AidanGoldie I have added Acess policies in key vault and RBAC role will also work if it has been granted correctly

It seems there may be a networking issue on my end and that's why I cannot access the Key Vault, I have used a .env file instead and the function now runs. Can I ask what your method was to retrieve all the modules for the requirements.txt file? Using 'pigar generate' didn't retrieve all necessary modules (only the ones I originally had when first posting this question) and 'pip freeze > requirements.txt' added too many modules to the file (both when the virtual environment was activated and deactivated), Thanks :)

@AidanGoldie I have created them manually and then added in requirement.txt file
